# Extract values after the 2nd occurrence of _ (underscore) and before dot (.) in bash

Tags: bash, awk, cut, cat

I have a file with some lines written in it in a temp directory. My goal is to extract the value between the 2nd underscore and the dot (.). For example,

Here is a sample of the contents of `filesample.txt`:

```
--rwxr-x---                    235 2016-08-24 05:13 File_Name_2696553.txt
--rwxr-x---                   1274 2016-09-14 04:44 File_Name_2852659.xls
--rwxr-x---                   1802 2016-09-14 05:04 File_Name_2852992.pdf
```

What I have done is the following:

```
cat ${tmp}filesample.txt | cut -b64- | awk -F"." '{ print $1 }'
```

This gives me the desired output. But, I think a better solution for this would be to have code that would look between the second underscore and the dot.

This way if the 7 digit number at the end of the contents of each line changes to 8 or more, I don't have to come back to my script and adjust it since `cut -b64-` is looking at the 64th position byte.

This is probably a basic question, I'm new to bash scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{split($NF, a, "[_.]"); print a[3]}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk '{split($NF, a, "[_.]"); print a[3]}' file
2696553
2852659
2852992
```

Comment: Using this solution: `awk '{split($NF, a, "[_.]"); print a[3]}' <<< 'a.b.c.d_123_xyz.jpg'`  will return `c` but I believe OP is looking for `xyz`

Answer (score 2):

To get value between 2nd `_` and next `DOT` you can use:

```
awk '{split($NF, a, /_/); sub(/\..*/, "", a[3]); print a[3]}' filesample.txt

2696553
2852659
2852992
```

- Using `split` function we are are splitting last filed by `_` (underscore) and take `a[3]` which is the value after 2nd `_`
- Then using `sub` function we strip off everything after `DOT` thus giving us value between 2nd `_` and next DOT

Comment: What is this line doing? Can you explain?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*_\([^.]*\).*/\1/' filesample.txt
2696553
2852659
2852992
```

It captures and outputs the value between last underscore and last dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
--rwxr-x---                    235 2016-08-24 05:13 File_Name_2696553.txt
--rwxr-x---                   1274 2016-09-14 04:44 File_Name_2852659.xls
--rwxr-x---                   1802 2016-09-14 05:04 File_Name_2852992.pdf

$ grep -oP '.*_\K\d+' ip.txt 
2696553
2852659
2852992
```

- `o` output only matched text
- `P` use perl based regex
- `.*_` match text upto `_` in a greedy manner
- `\K` use positive lookbehind, matched text until then won't be part of output
- `\d+` one or more digits

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file

2696553
2852659
2852992
```

Comment: Let's improve then:)!